# Power BI - En una gráfico de líneas mostrar el top N de cada año

Tags: powerbi

Tengo una tabla de pruebas con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando realiza una gráfica de líneas para cada año en particular (2013-2014) con el top 5 de países por quantity obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando quiero representar estos dos gráficos en uno solo, estoy teniendo una respuesta muy diferente a la anterior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según entiendo, el sistema está calculando el Top 5 general correspondiente a ambos años y me muestra esa información en las dos gráficas (es por ello que los nombres de los países cambian).

Es posible con este tipo de chart mostrar la información como la solicito?

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes usar dos stacked bar charts?

Comment: Hola. No el requerimiento por alguna razón exige que se muestre en una sola imagen el resultado del ejercicio. Los dos años que puse son sólo a modo de ejemplo. Se quieren mostrar algunos mas.